# Firebase Database OutofMemory Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, out-of-memory, firebase-storage

I want to fetch all my json child so I could you my app offline. I do the syncing when my app first start. As it contains too much data in database my app got crashes many times and it's not able to fetch all data.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.manish.firebaseexample, PID: 12234
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdyi.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>                                                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
>                                                                                   at bma.toString(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746036:11)
>                                                                                   at bkq.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746036:82)
>                                                                                   at bkv.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746036:9)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

My Database Image

[image]

[image: Varieties Details]

```
 refDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("INT").child("varieties");
    refDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    refDatabase.getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG,""+dataSnapshot.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG,databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

As "image" data contains the Base64 encoded image.

Comment: So expand a node in varieties and update/edit your question with how large is it? What does each one contain and how many are you trying to read at one time?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you're retrieving more data than can be expanded in your phone's memory. There are 2 ways for solving that.

> 1. To free your phone's memory to hold more data.
> 2. To filter data using one of the filtering methods.

Please see the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) regarding filtering data within Firebase.

Comment: Another helpful answer, if this is not worked for anyone. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51175188/8123983